# In MongoDB how do I convert seconds after epoch to Datetimes?

Tags: mongodb, datetime

In MongoDB how do I convert seconds after epoch to Datetimes in a query?

I'm looking for the equivalent to the following Python function

```
In [10]: datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1000000000)
Out[10]: datetime.datetime(2001, 9, 9, 1, 46, 40)
```

I understand that it would have been nicer to just insert datetimes directly, sadly that isn't my situation.

In particular I'm using the aggregation pipeline query system, so something that fits neatly into that framework is preferable.

Comment: What is the greater objective that you want to accomplish? You want to change the data or do some specific query?

Comment: I want to do a query, not change data.  I'm also building a tool though, so general solutions are preferable.  I'll make an edit.

Comment: is this in javascript server functions? you should be able to do `new Date(unixTime*1000)` to get a JS date object (the *1000 is since JS expects this value in milliseconds).

Comment: I'd like to accomplish this through the aggregation pipeline query system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The arithmetic operators of aggregation framework are able to handle the conversion.
(run on mongo shell)

```
// initialize for test
var date = new Date();
date.setMilliseconds(0);
var epochSeconds = date.getTime() / 1000;
db.c.insert({date : date, epochSeconds : epochSeconds});

// perform test
var baseDate = new Date(0);
db.c.aggregate([{
    $project: {
        date : 1, 
        newDate : {
            $add : [ baseDate, {
                $multiply : [ "$epochSeconds", 1000 ]
            }]
        }
    }
}, 
// optional, just for easier to determine
{
    $project : {
        date : 1,
        newDate : 1,
        comparison : {
            $cond : {
                "if" : {
                    $eq : [ "$date", "$newDate" ]
                },
                "then" : "equal",
                "else" : "not equal"
            }
        }
    }
}]).pretty();
```

And the output like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("545460af6e66646769ae0a9d"),
    "date" : ISODate("2014-11-01T04:25:18Z"),
    "newDate" : ISODate("2014-11-01T04:25:18Z"),
    "comparison" : "equal"
}
```